# Aura Template to get child components by `data` attribute

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, page-template

It seems I can't access child LWC components while I am using the controller.js from an Aura Template for Record Page. Everything returns back a length of 0. I've tried `document.querySelectorAll` and `this.querySelectorAll` as well.

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var components = this.document.querySelectorAll('[data-step-id]');
}
```

And the child LWC html

```
<template>
    <div data-step-id="1">
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You may want to ask about your "X" so we can give you useful answers instead the answer I provided, which is accurate but useless to achieving your goals.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. You cannot get elements within a LWC, as they are blocked by the "[shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom)". This means that each component is a "black box" with respect to its parent components. The same is also true if you use a LWC within another LWC. You cannot access the internal elements of another component. This is by design.